# How do you use catalogs in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, file-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best practices with Lightroom libraries](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2108/best-practices-with-lightroom-libraries)

Or perhaps, how do you organize your photos in Lightroom 3?

I got a feeling that the way I do it is not very convenient.

The flow that I do on every new set of photos is:

1. Copy the photos from the camera to
   a new folder on the HD (e.g. to
   C:\Photos\Bobs_bday_2010).
2. Create a New Catalog, and save it to the
   same directory where the photos are.
3. Import all
   photos from the directory to this
   catalog.

Does it make sense? Should I use catalogs for photos organization, or should I rather use something else? Should I create a new catalog for each new set of photos, and where to save all these catalogs?

Thank you!