# How do you organize your photos on your computer?

Tags: file-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I better organise and file my photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-can-i-better-organise-and-file-my-photos)

I've just purchased a DSLR camera. As I wait for it to arrive I'm wondering how I'm going to keep my photos organized as they start to add up. Of course I've been taking snapshots of family, etc for years. But I've never really figured out a good organizational system. I will soon start to take more and more photos for artistic purposes that have nothing to do with my previous categories of photographs.

What are some ways that I can organize all these photos so that I know which folder houses a given photo?

Note: Could someone make this a community wiki?

Comment: I use Shotwell on Linux, which organizes pictures by date: `/year/month/day/{pictures}`. But it supports creating tags, events, etc. Make sure to get in the habit of tagging *every photo you import*. It will make management *so* much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 2 main folders : one for everyday life pictures, another for artistic pictures.

```
EveryDay
   Family
       ........
   Holidays
       2010.10.28 - Groenland
   Events
       2011.01.01 - New year's day

Artistic
    Great To develop
    Developed
    Photoshoots
       2010
           2010.05.17 - Priscillia shoot
           2010.05.17 - Flowers in the square
       2011
           ..........
    Others
        Clouds
        Textures
        .........
```

This allows me to quickly find a wanted picture.

In complement, I use a picture catalog software to manage and browse those folders, mainly to be able to find pictures from EXIF datas.